# While returning promise it gives me an unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs

This the factory.

```
latModule.factory('latSvc',
[
    "$http", "$scope", "$q",
    function($http, $scope, $q) {
        console.log("Enter latUserReportDateSvc");

        return {
            getPromiseForUserReportDate: function () {
                $scope.userId = "bpx3364";
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get('/api/UserReportStatusApi', { 'userId': $scope.userId }).then(function(reponse) {
                        deferred.resolve(reponse);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            getPromiseForLocation: function () {
                $scope.userId = "bpx3364";
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get('api/UserAccountApi/', { 'userId': $scope.userId }).then(function (reponse) {
                    deferred.resolve(reponse);
                },
                    function (error) {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            getPromiseForErrorSummary: function (userInfoVm) {
                console.log("latErrorSummarySvc getErrorCounts, userInfo: ", userInfoVm);
                $scope.userId = "bpx3364";
                $scope.serviceTypeCode = 4;
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get('/api/UserReportStatusApi', { 'userId': $scope.userId, 'serviceTypeCode': $scope.serviceTypeCode }).then(function (reponse) {
                    deferred.resolve(reponse);
                },
                    function (error) {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            }

        };


    }
]);
```

This is the controller

```
latModule.controller("dashboardController",
    ["$scope","latSvc",
function ($scope,latSvc) {
    console.log("enter dashboard controller");

    console.log("scope: ", $scope);

    console.log("homeUserInfo: ", $scope.homeLatUserInfo);


  var dashboardUserReportDate = function() {
        latSvc.getUserReportDateInfo().then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.dashboardUserReportDateData = response;

            }, function(error) {}
        );
    };
    dashboardUserReportDate();
    var dashboardErrorCounts = function() {
        latSvc.getPromiseForErrorSummary($scope.homeLatUserInfo).then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.dashboardErrorCountsData = response;

            },
            function (error) { }
        );
    };
    dashboardErrorCounts();
    var dashboardAtmCount = function() {
        latSvc.getPromiseForLocation().then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.dashboardAtmCountData = response;
            }, function(error) {}
        );
    };

    dashboardAtmCount();
}]);
```

after running this code I am getting an unknown provider error while I am trying to implement this promise concept.Because while I was calling through service with out resolving promise and without using then the url was getting hit multiple times.

Comment: Can you please exact error you are getting?

Comment: You should write the code to return the promise from `facory` or `service`. It should be `return $http.get()` from the `factory` and use the returned promise in your controller.

Comment: Can you please show a sample of your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use / inject $scope into a service. 
But as far as I understand your code you should be fine using local variables for your http request query parameters.

And Vineet is right - you should return the $http.get() directly (it's already a promise).